# Derivative of $\ z=v^{3}u^{5} $ by chain rule and substitution

Tags: derivatives

Let $\ z=u^{3}v^{5} $ where $\ u=x+y, v=x-y $ Find $\ \frac{dz}{dy} $
For that I just did
$$\ \frac{dz}{dy}=\frac{dz}{du}\frac{du}{dy}+\frac{dz}{dv}\frac{dv}{dy} $$
And I got: $$\ 3(x+y)^{2}(y-5)^{5}+5(x+y)^{3}(x-y)^{4}$$ Is this right?

This is the solution by the chain rule, right?
But then the problem says I need to make substitution and explicit computation, but I have no idea of this, It was not covered in the lectures.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dz}{du}=3u^2v^5$$ and $$\frac{du}{dy}=1$$ because for $\frac{du}{dy}$ you treat $x$ as a constant. Now you substitute the expressions for $u$ and $v$.

The second part is calculated similarly.